# delete the read permission from a file

Tags: permissions, root, chmod

So, let's say I have a file named `FILE`. Whenever someone wants to edit or read it (for example `cat FILE` in terminal), it should ask for root password.

How to do this? I suppose there's a `chmod` command, but I can't figure out, even on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that a file could be edited only by root, you should make root the owner of it:

```
chown root FILE
```

and then change permissions so that just the owner can write/read it:

```
chmod 600 FILE
```

Your solution simply make the file unreadable by everyone. Check permission, owner etc with

```
ls -l FILE
```

Consider, too, that the right to delete the file depends on the owner and permission of the directory where it is located, so that if `FILE` is in directory owned by you, where you have the permission to write to, you can delete `FILE`.

And again, this will not simply ask for a root password --- it will spew a "permission denied" error, and then you'll have to use `sudo`to read/edit it.